# Java combine classes correct

Tags: java, class, object

I have following classes, House, Villa, WoodenHouse, Garage, Door and Windows.

Only Villa could have garages.
I have int opening in House for the number of doors+windows.
And area in garage for the garage area.

Now i want to generate a House  Villa/WoodenHouse with number of doors, windows and if it is able to garage if so the area.

I created every class but i'm stuck with the constructors.
Don't know how to link them correctly.

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class House {
private int opening;

public int getOpenings(){
        return opening;
    }

public House(String Art) {
        if (Art=="Villa") {
            House = new House(new Villa(Villa.))
        }
    }


}
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Villa extends House {

private Garage garage;

Garage garage = new Garage(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Garage area"));


}
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class WoodenHouse extends House{
public WoodenHouse() {

}
}
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Garage {
private int Area;

public void setArea(int f) {
    Area = f;   
}

public int getArea() {
    return Area;
}


}
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Doors {
int AmountD;
}

public class Windows {
int AmountW;
}
```

Want to end up with House1 = new House(Which one, Amount Doors, Amount Windows, Garage?)
Any things so i can end up with that?

Comment: If you can provide some pseudo-code, and point out where you have problem, it will help in understanding the problem.

Comment: import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Haus {
 private int oeffnungen;
 
 
 
 
 
 
 public int getOeffnungen(){
  return oeffnungen;
 }
 
 public Haus(String Art) {
 if (Art=="Villa") {
  Villa.Garage
 }
 }
 
}

Comment: import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Villa extends Haus {

private Garage garage;

garage = new Garage(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Fläche der Garage"));


}

Comment: import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Holzhütte extends Haus{
public Holzhütte() {
 
}
}

Comment: import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Garage {
private int Flaeche;

public void setFlaeche(int f) {
 Flaeche = f; 
}

public int getFlaeche() {
 return Flaeche;
}


}

Comment: import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Tueren {
int AnzahlT;
}

Comment: public class Fenster {
int AnzahlF;
}

Comment: Problem to set the new object in Haus (House) with Villa/WoodenHouse + Doors, Windows, Garage

Comment: If category == Villa { new Villa .........

Comment: Put the sample code directly in your question (edit your question to include that text) instead of putting it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

How I would approach this:
I would have an interface `HasGarages`, with a method `int numberOfGarages()` or some such.
Another interface `HouseDetails`, with methods `int opening()` and `int area()`.
A third interface `HasGaragesAndMore` (or some such) which extends both.
Then have the classes implement the interface they need to.